# connect mssql database on Centos 8 using php 7.4

Tags: centos, database, php7, sqlserver

I cannot figure out the way to connect **MSSQL 2014** database on **centos 8** using **PhP 7.4**.
I found [GitHub link](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/v5.8.0/CentOS7-7.4.tar) and downloaded [CentOS8-7.4.tar](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/download/v5.8.0/CentOS8-7.4.tar)
 and extracted the **php_sqlsrv_72_ts.so** and **php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.so**. but not sure where to paste the  modules like

> windows => xampp folder > php >> extensions

> edit php.ini; extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts and restart web server

Any help or guidance is really appreciated.
Here are the commands I did run:

```
dnf -y update
dnf install yum-utils http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm -y
dnf module reset php
dnf module enable php:remi-7.4
yum module reset nginx
yum module enable nginx:1.16
dnf install wget nginx php-fpm mariadb-server php-mysqli php-gd php-imap php-xml php-mbstring php-intl php-pecl-apcu php-opcache php-pecl-zip
systemctl enable --now nginx php-fpm mariadb
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http --add-service=https
firewall-cmd --reload
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $serverName = "ServerIP\Instance";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dummydatabase", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"mystrongpasswrod",'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=> true);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
    if( $conn === false ) {
      die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    else{
      echo 'Successfully Connected';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT,
run the commands below:

```
dnf install php-pear php-devel unixODBC-devel make

pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

#https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/8/prod/
dnf -y install https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/8/prod/msodbcsql17-17.6.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm

echo 'extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so' > /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini

echo 'extension=sqlsrv.so' > /etc/php.d/30-sqlsrv.ini

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: Can you clarify if this is for the client connecting to your MSSQL server, or for the MSSQL server itself, to allow remote connections?